# Jumbo Frames on DIR-842

Tags: networking, jumbo-frames

Are Jumbo Frames supported by the D-Link DIR-842? If so, which maximum size?

It supports 1 Gbit/s so I guess it should but I'm not sure, haven't found much while Googling.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the specifications?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/197569/jumbo-frames-on-dir-655?rq=1

Comment: Yes; They are supported based on my research.  How large of a frame will depend on the clients connected to the LAN ports

Comment: The specs doesn't mention "Jumbo Frames" and there's no option in the web UI to configure it in the DHCP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, jumbo frames are supported in the LAN part of the DIR-842. I've tested this by connecting two gigabit NICs to the LAN ports and sent 9 KB frames between them.

But, the maximum MTU size for the WAN (under IPv4 settings) is 1500, configurable in the web GUI.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to be more specific about what exactly you tested, and how? Did you send a 9k ping from a machine on one LAN port to a machine on another LAN port? Did you send a 9k ping to the router itself and get a reply back? Did you send a 9k ping from LAN to WAN? Did you run a sniffer to ensure you were sending the 9k ping as a single packet?

Comment: @Spiff, I Think the answer is better now.